# Why I can set value for a property that only has a GET

Tags: c#

Sorry it is a dumb question, just learning from a book and I saw this code:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

My question is how is this working? There is no `set;` and we are assigning a value to that property.

Comment: It's a read-only property, which *can* be set in the constructor.

Comment: is there a difference from using `readonly`?

Comment: @rfmodulator Can we only do that in CTOR?

Comment: @draz Well, you can't add the `readonly` modifier to a property, so yes? `public readonly IConfiguration Configuration { get; }` will not build.

Comment: @Bohn You can also do `public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = [some IConfiguration];` But at any rate, the property is *only* able to be set when the class is instantiated.

Comment: of course you would not need the `{get;}`. but actually this answers my question: it would not be a property anymore but a field, which might be important in some use-cases. thanks

Comment: @draz That is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as an "Auto-Implemented Property" ("auto property", for short), because there is no "backing field" (or get accessor logic) defined, so the compiler creates a backing field automatically.

A property ("auto" or otherwise) with only a get accessor is a read-only property.

A read-only auto property may be set (initialized) in the constructor, as shown.

Auto properties may also be initialized when declared:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = [some IConfiguration];
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I learned it.